# How to aggregate on one column and take maximum of others in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have columns `X` (string), `Y` (string), and `Z` (float).

And I want to

- aggregate on X
- take the maximum of column Z
- report ALL the values for columns X, Y, and Z

If there are multiple values for column Y that correspond to the maximum for column Z, then take the maximum of those values in column Y.

For example, my table is like:  `table1`:

```
col X col Y col Z
A     1     5
A     2     10
A     3     10
B     5     15
```

resulting in:

```
A     3     10
B     5     15
```

If I were using SQL, I would do it like this:

```
select X, Y, Z 
from table1 
join (select max(Z) as max_Z from table1 group by X) table2
on table1.Z = table2.max_Z
```

However how do I do this when 1) column Z is a float?  and 2)  I'm using pyspark sql?

Answer (score 3):

The two following solutions are in Scala, but honestly could not resist posting them to promote my beloved window aggregate functions. Sorry.

The only question is which structured query is more performant/effective?

### Window Aggregate Function: rank

```
val df = Seq(
  ("A",1,5),
  ("A",2,10),
  ("A",3,10),
  ("B",5,15)
).toDF("x", "y", "z")

scala> df.show
+---+---+---+
|  x|  y|  z|
+---+---+---+
|  A|  1|  5|
|  A|  2| 10|
|  A|  3| 10|
|  B|  5| 15|
+---+---+---+

// describe window specification
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
val byX = Window.partitionBy("x").orderBy($"z".desc).orderBy($"y".desc)

// use rank to calculate the best X
scala> df.withColumn("rank", rank over byX)
  .select("x", "y", "z")
  .where($"rank" === 1) // <-- take the first row
  .orderBy("x")
  .show
+---+---+---+
|  x|  y|  z|
+---+---+---+
|  A|  3| 10|
|  B|  5| 15|
+---+---+---+
```

### Window Aggregate Function: first and dropDuplicates

I've always been thinking about the alternatives to `rank` function and `first` usually sprung to mind.

```
// use first and dropDuplicates
scala> df.
  withColumn("y", first("y") over byX).
  withColumn("z", first("z") over byX).
  dropDuplicates.
  orderBy("x").
  show
+---+---+---+
|  x|  y|  z|
+---+---+---+
|  A|  3| 10|
|  B|  5| 15|
+---+---+---+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can consider using `Window` function. My approach here is to create Window function that partition dataframe by `X` first. Then, order columns `Y` and `Z` by its value.

- We can simply select `rank == 1` for row that we're interested.
- Or we can use `first` and `drop_duplicates` to achieve the same task.

PS. Thanks Jacek Laskowski for the comments and Scala solution that leads to this solution.

### Create toy example dataset

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as func

data=[('A',1,5),
      ('A',2,10),
      ('A',3,10),
      ('B',5,15)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data,schema=['X','Y','Z'])
```

### Window Aggregate Function: rank

Apply windows function with `rank` function

```
w = Window.partitionBy(df['X']).orderBy([func.col('Y').desc(), func.col('Z').desc()])
df_max = df.select('X', 'Y', 'Z', func.rank().over(w).alias("rank"))
df_final = df_max.where(func.col('rank') == 1).select('X', 'Y', 'Z').orderBy('X')
df_final.show()
```

**Output**

```
+---+---+---+
|  X|  Y|  Z|
+---+---+---+
|  A|  3| 10|
|  B|  5| 15|
+---+---+---+
```

### Window Aggregate Function: first and drop_duplicates

This task can also be achieved by using `first` and `drop_duplicates` as follows

```
df_final = df.select('X', func.first('Y').over(w).alias('Y'), func.first('Z').over(w).alias('Z'))\
    .drop_duplicates()\
    .orderBy('X')
df_final.show()
```

**Output**

```
+---+---+---+
|  X|  Y|  Z|
+---+---+---+
|  A|  3| 10|
|  B|  5| 15|
+---+---+---+
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets create a dataframe from your sample data as -

```
data=[('A',1,5),
('A',2,10),
('A',3,10),
('B',5,15)]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data,schema=['X','Y','Z'])
df.show()
```

output:

```
+---+---+---+
|  X|  Y|  Z|
+---+---+---+
|  A|  1|  5|
|  A|  2| 10|
|  A|  3| 10|
|  B|  5| 15|
+---+---+---+
```

:

```
# create a intermediate dataframe that find max of Z 
df1 = df.groupby('X').max('Z').toDF('X2','max_Z')
```

:

```
 # create 2nd intermidiate dataframe that finds max of Y where Z =  max of Z

 df2 = df.join(df1,df.X==df1.X2)\
        .where(col('Z')==col('max_Z'))\
        .groupBy('X')\
        .max('Y').toDF('X','max_Y')
```

:

```
# join above two to form final result

result = df1.join(df2,df1.X2==df2.X)\
            .select('X','max_Y','max_Z')\
            .orderBy('X')

result.show()
```

:

```
+---+-----+-----+
|  X|max_Y|max_Z|
+---+-----+-----+
|  A|    3|   10|
|  B|    5|   15|
+---+-----+-----+
```

Comment: Your statement `finds max of Y where Z =  max of Z` <--- this seems like trouble to me because you are comparing floating point values.  I'm not sure spark will handle that consistently the same every time. Any way around this?

Comment: "I'm not sure spark will handle that consistently" -- can you please elaborate more on this with actual data sample , if possible?